# How to detect an existing installation of IIS using INNO setup?

Tags: delphi, iis, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am looking for a way to determine if the user already has a version of IIS installed. If he doesn't, I will go ahead and run my IIS installation script.

I know of the exception handling clause where I do :

```
  try
    IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');  
  except  
    RaiseException(ExceptionType, ‘IIS not installed. Setup will now install IIS on your machine. ’#13#13'(Error ‘’’+ExceptionParam+’’’ occured)’);  
  end;
```

but for some reason, my compiler version doesn't seem to recognise RaiseException. I also tried including

```
uses  
SysUtils;
```

but the compiler won't recognize SysUtils even. Is there something like a registry key that I can look at to determine whether IIS is already installed or not?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: By _my compiler version_ you mean the IIS Pascal Script interpreter? Or you mean a real (delphi) compiler?

Comment: I mean the INNO Pascal Script interpreter. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Oh and thanks for fixing my code formatting. Will keep it in mind in the future :)

Comment: Does not work with IIS7 :{

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rishi you are using the `RaiseException` function with 2 parameters, but the this function only support one.

```
procedure RaiseException(const Msg: String);
```

try using this function like this

```
var
 IIS : variant;
begin    
  try
    IIS := CreateOleObject('IISNamespace');
  except
    RaiseException('IIS not installed. Setup will now install IIS on your machine');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that also. What happens is that for some odd reason, the exception is not caught. The code never reaches inside of the except. I am beginning to think that I am missing some sort of 'uses' clause? Thanks for your help

Comment: My bad. This works fine. I just saw the exception because I was debugging in INNO's debugger instead of running the exe. Thanks

Comment: It's not working for me. I installed the IIS version 10.0.16299.15, but this code raises exception as not installed. Please any one help. Thanks.

Comment: If this requires IIS 6 Compatibility to be enabled, then many machines today won't have that.

Answer (score 2):

IIS always installs to %windir%\system32\inetsrv so you should check if specific files exist under this directory. For example, w3wp.exe should exist in this folder for IIS 6/7.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
[CustomMessages]
iis_title=Internet Information Services (IIS)


[Code]
function iis(): boolean;
begin
    if not RegKeyExists(HKLM, 'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\W3SVC\Security') then
        MsgBox(FmtMessage(CustomMessage('depinstall_missing'), [CustomMessage('iis_title')]), mbError, MB_OK)
    else
        Result := true;
end
```

;